# Correct frontend mapping of TCA 'type'=>'check'

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I currently implement a user right object in TYPO3 7/Extbase. Different rights are mapped as bits of an INT as per (simplified):

```
'permissions' => array(
 'label' => 'permissions'
 'config' => array(
  'type' => 'check',
  'items' => array(
   array('Permission 1', ''),
   array('Permission 2', '')
  )
 )
),
```

Modification of this in the Backend works flawlessly and the flags are correctly stored as their corresponding bits in he DB.

How can I achieve similar behaviour in the frontend? Is there a (correct) way of mapping the bit values to fluid checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add custom setter/getter functions that set or return the bits.

in your model:

```
/**
 * @var int
 */
protected $permissions;
```

Add something like this:

```
/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getPermission2() {
  return $this->permissions & 2 > 0 ? 1 : 0;
}

/**
 * @param int $permission2
 */
public function getPermission2($permission2) {
  if ($permission2) {
    $this->permissions = $this->permissions | 2;
  } else {
    $this->permissions = $this->permissions ~ 2;
  }
}
```

Then you can `parameter="permission2"` in the `f:form.checkbox` or `{object.permission2}` for other fluid viewhelpers.

PS: for permission 1 you need to change the `2` to `1` and for permission 3 it would be `4`

Comment: Ah, right, I didn't think of custom setters/getters for this. This would encapsulate the data structure nicely and allow use of direct property mapping to the fluid components. For now I have solved this by processing the current value into single booleans per bit and assigning this to the view as an array (and vice versa when updating).

Comment: It would be nice if you'd give reference material, I got what you're talking about but that gets little up and running ... I have the same issue with weekdays, so 7 checkboxes !